# Form button, conneted to Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

I want to connect a form to Firebase. How can i connect the button in Html with Firebase by using JavaScript

HTML:

```
<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
  <form  id="add-data" class="form-container">
    <button type="submit" class="btn">XXXX"</button>
  </form>
```

In JavaScript:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    db.collection('xxxx').add({        
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside ur javascript:

```
//Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "API_KEY",
  authDomain: "PROJECT_ID.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://PROJECT_ID.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "PROJECT_ID",
  storageBucket: "PROJECT_ID.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "SENDER_ID",
  appId: "APP_ID",
  measurementId: "G-MEASUREMENT_ID",
};

// Initialize Firebase
var db = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

//continue ur code here...
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
db.collection('xxxx').add({
    
})`
```

Comment: I have connected it with firebase, and a receive date. Butt it will not send data when i push submit button. I have all the add value code, butt it Will not submit.

Comment: Your Javascript Submit Listener code has to gather the values from the various form elements, and format them as an object for .add() . This has nothing whatever to do with firestore, and everything to do with HTML and Javascript.  THe fragments you show here do not show how (or IF) you do that.